# gitlab API unathorized

Tags: api, gitlab

I tried to create a project by importing manually my git repo. I followed that tutorial :
  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md

At the end I got that error :

 `* Failed trying to create xxx (xxx/xxx.git)
   Errors: {:base=>["Failed to create repository via gitlab-shell"]}`

By reading gitlab-shell.log file I discover that access to the API is forbidden I got the following error :

`{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}`

With that URL :

`https://xxx/api/v4/internal/check`

Do you know how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a HTTP Post request in order to achieve this.
Clearly, according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html you do not have the authorization. This is because you are not using the Gitlab Private token.

You can go to Profile -> settings -> generate a Private token. Once generated, copy it to your clipboard and use it in your post request.

Best way to use it is by Curl:
Ex:

curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXX -k "https://example.com//api/v4/projects/11/jobs/16863/retry"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I already have a private token. I got that issue because I'm trying to import from a git repository into GitLab. I did it manually following the tutorial in my first post. The last step of that tutorial is the issue with the error I posted above.

Comment: I don't know if it is related but in production.log I have the following errors : ```Raven 2.4.0 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set
Unable to save project. Error: Failed to create repository```

Answer (score -1):

u need to genrate private Token :

open your account gitlab -> settings->genrate private Token

Comment: This repeats the other answer.